# Woher kommt die Redewendung „mit dem linken Bein aufstehen“?

Tags: word-usage, idiom

> Ich steige immer mit dem linken Bein aus dem Bett.

Die Bedeutung ist hier, dass ich eine schlechte Laune habe, wenn ich aufstehe; aber meine Frage ist, warum mit dem linken Bein, warum nicht mit dem rechten  Bein? Woher kommt diese  Redewendung?

Comment: Ich kenne das als "mit dem falschen Bein" aufstehen. Falsch ist das Gegenteil von richtig, in alter Form recht, das Gegenteil von rechts ist links. Vielleicht hat es sich so entwicklet?

Comment: Ich kenne das als „mit dem linken Fuß zuerst aufstehen“ in der Bedeutung, dass an dem Tag einfach alles schief läuft.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Laut Duden, Band 11 *Redewendungen* (3. Auflage 2008) wurzelt die umgangssprachliche Redewendung

> mit dem linken/falschen Bein/Fuß [zuerst] aufgestanden sein

in der abergläubischen Auffassung, dass die linke Seite die Unglücksseite sei. Mit dem linken, dem verkehrten Bein aufzustehen, galt somit als schlechtes Vorzeichen.

So geht beispielsweise auch die Wendung

> jemanden/etwas links liegen lassen

angeblich darauf zurück, dass die linke Seite im Volksglauben als Seite des Bösen, Unheilvollen galt, mit dem man nichts zu tun haben wollte.

Comment: Ja ich glaube deswegen halten wir auch das Messer in der rechten (guten) Hand.

Comment: Den Duden kann man in solchen Fragen getrost links liegen lassen

Comment: Diese Art von Aberglauben gab es schon bei den alten Römern, vgl. in der *Cena Trimalchionis* von Petronius die Aufforderung an die Gäste, den Raum mit dem rechten Fuß zuerst zu betreten ("*Dextro pede!*").

Answer (score 2):

Dieses Sprichwort stammt aus dem Mittelalter. Häufig hatte man auf der Seite des Bettes zu der man für gewöhnlich nicht aufsteht den Nachttopf stehen. Ist man zur falschen Seite aufgestanden stand man somit mit den Fuß darin. Daher auch die Redensart „mit dem falschen Fuß“, da ein Fuß egal ob man nach rechts oder links aufsteht, zuerst den Boden berührt. Ist man hingegen zur „richtigen“ oder „rechten“ Seite aufgestanden stand man nicht mit den Füßen im Nachttopf. Später entwickelte sich aus „nicht zur rechten“ die ohnehin unheilvolle linke Seite des Bettes bei der der linke Fuß zuerst im Nachttopf wahr. Man konnte die unglücklich Erwachten daran erkennen, dass sie sich fluchend einen Fuß wuschen.

Comment: Irgendein Beleg dafür?

Comment: https://www.heimatlexikon-thaleischweiler-froeschen.de/index.php/tourismus-48/91-heimatmuseum

Answer (score 1):

Der übliche Ausdruck heißt ja, *mit dem falschen Bein aufgestanden*.

Ich vermute, dass sich die Variante mit dem linken Bein entwickelt hat aus *nicht mit dem rechten Bein ausgestanden*, wobei *rechtes* hier zweideutigerweise im Sinne von *richtig* gebraucht wird, nicht als Angabe der Seite.

Jemand wird das fälschlicherweise als Seitenangabe verstanden haben und so wurde aus "nicht rechtes" eben "linkes".

Answer (score 0):

die Assoziation zwischen *links* und *schlecht* ist althergebracht, eventuel missverstanden, in diesem Fall aber vermutlich auf die Nebenbedeutung *falsch, schwach* zurückzuführen. Jedenfalls findet sich oft ein *linker Kerl*, der als Beispiel für das dem Worte immanente *Unrecht* herhalten muss. So übrigens auch in Latein *sinister*.

So findet sich auch *mit dem falschen Fuß*, ohne Seitenangabe, da für den Unterbau eine starke Rechts-Links-Ausprägung nicht zu beobachten ist. Dass hier ursprünglich der Fuß der linken Körperhälfte gemeint war ist deswegen nicht glaubhaft. Bei Übelkeit sagt man auch, *mir ist schlecht*.

Näherliegend wäre eine Bedeutung ähnlich *mit wackeligen Beinen*, insoweit die Bedeutung *schwach* in *link* mit einer bedeutung *hängend* assoziiert wird, die auch in *anhängen*, Latein *linquo* "folgen" zu vermuten ist (vgl auch *Delinquent*). Vergleich auch *schlecht* vs *schlacksig* (eventuell auch *-lecht* zu *link*; sieht erstmal nicht danach aus, *schlecht* wird zu *schlick* gestellt, "slippery" [en.wiktionary], das passt ja zum Thema).

Darin kann ein weiterer, weniger abergläubischer Bedeutungsansatz für die *Linke* gesehen werden, nämlich *die andere, Nachfolgende, Zweite*. Vergleich auch *übel* vs *übrig*, quasi die *übrige* Hand.

---

Ferner ist *Fuß* zwar relativ eindeutig, *Bein* dagegen, nur zum Beispiel, erfuhr semantische Verjüngung(?), bedeutete einst *Knochen* (vgl *Gebein*, En *bone*).

*podon*, *pes*, verwandt mit *Fuß*, bedeutete aber auch *Basis*, vgl. *Podest*. Nun weiß einjeder dass ein kräftiges Frühstück eine notwendige Basis für den Start in einen Erfolgreichen Tag ist. Und von Hunger kriegt man schlechte Laune.

Es sei dahingestellt, ob es einst ein allgemein mickriges Morgenbrot, oder speziel *left-overs*, also das was am Vortag sozusagen *linkgeblieben* war, gewesen ist.

---

Ein möglicher Ansatz wäre noch verschlafen, im Gegensatz zur *rechten* Zeit. Ein Bezug zu Füßen ist darin aber nicht ersichtlich. Allenfalls ein weiter Weg über Zeit, Rhytmus, Versfuß und Iambus (Gr *Schenkel*?) wäre interessant, scheint hier aber abwegig.

---

PS: Die Geschichte mit dem Nachttopf ist fantastisch, erklärt aber nicht, weshalb der Spruch weite Bedeutung erlangt hat, wenn er diese nicht schon vorher gehabt haben sollte. Außer man stellt sich vor im Mittelalter gab es unzählige Idioten. Na klar, im Dunkeln, als es noch kein elektrisches Licht gab, trat man schnell mal ins Fettnäpfchen ... und verfluchte die den Teufel, die alte Schlange, dass er schon wieder die Sonne gefressen hat. Das kann alles zur Wahrung und Verzerrung einer älteren Phrase beigetragen haben.